# Android Studio - Order an Array of 2 dimensions by 3 different Columns

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

I'm facing problems about how to order a 2 dimensions array by several columns.
Maybe I shouldn't use arrays. I would like to know your opinion and if there is an elegant way to do it.

I have the file "Example.txt" with the following rows:

1|A|C|Something

2|A|V|Something

2|B|C|Something

3|B|C|Something

3|A|C|Something

3|A|V|Something

3|B|V|Something

4|A|C|Something

Which I can easily extract them and store in the array Example [][].

Below you can find the part of the code to read from the file:

public class ActivityExample extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);

    int Max_Linhas=100;
    int Max_Colunas=10;
    int Linha=0;

    String[][] Example = new String[Max_Linhas][Max_Colunas];

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("Example.txt");

        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String receiveString = "";

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {


                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(receiveString, "|");

                Example [Linha][0]= st.nextToken();
                Example [Linha][1]= st.nextToken();
                Example [Linha][2]= st.nextToken();
                Example [Linha][3]= st.nextToken();

                Linha++;

            }

            inputStream.close();

        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Somewhere here I would like to ORDER this array by Column 1, Column 0, column 2 ASCENDING
}
```

}

I have in the array Example[][] the values:

[ 1; A; C; Something ]

[ 2; A; V; Something ]

[ 2; B; C; Something ]

[ 3; B; C; Something ]

[ 3; A; C; Something ]

[ 3; A; V; Something ]

[ 3; B; V; Something ]

[ 4; A; C; Something ]

And I would like to order it by the column 2, column 1 and column 3 ascending.

The final result should be:

[ 1; A; C; Something ]

[ 2; A; V; Something ]

[ 3; A; C; Something ]

[ 3; A; V; Something ]

[ 4; A; C; Something ]

[ 2; B; C; Something ]

[ 3; B; C; Something ]

[ 3; B; V; Something ]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an array use a class to model the data.

```
class Model implements Comparable<Model> {
    String col1, col2, col3, col4;


    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull Model o) {
        // Assumes fields are not null
        int result = col2.compareTo(o.col2);
        if(result != 0){
            return result;
        }

        result = col1.compareTo(o.col1);
        if(result != 0){
            return result;
        }

        result = col3.compareTo(o.col3);
        if(result != 0){
            return result;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I also store the information of the file directly in other kind of variable (like a list of values)?
I mean, col1 is a list of the values of Example[i][0],  col2 is a list of the values of Example[i][1]....

Comment: Instead of Compare with Arrays, I created a ArrayList, with the Col2 as the first element, Col2 the second, Col3 the third element, then the forth column. I Sort the ArrayList [ with the function Collections.sort(ExampleLista); ] and finally I split the several fields into an array [ With the function LineSplit st = new StringTokenizer(ExampleItem, "|");]